# How to set shortcut for `Copy file path` in sublime text 3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3

How to set shortcut for `Copy file path` in sublime text 3?
I tried:

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+i"], "command": "copy_file_path" }
]
```

But seemingly command `copy_file_path` not valid.

[image: shortcut for "Copy file path" in sublime text 3]

Answer (score 72, accepted):

All you need to do is change `"copy_file_path"` to `"copy_path"`.

---

To discover this, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to open the console, then ran

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

to have all actions logged to the console. I then right-clicked and selected `Copy File Path`, and

```
command: copy_path
```

showed up. I assigned the key combination, ran it, and it worked. To finish up, I run

```
sublime.log_commands(False)
```

so the console doesn't get clogged with unnecessary info, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> again to close the console.

Comment: I would really appreciated if you could say how you came to know about `sublime.log_commands`? Probably sublime's API?

Comment: @Hamid yes, this is documented in Sublime's [API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html).

Comment: Great answer. thanks @MattDMo. Do I need to install a package for this? I tried right clicking on a file in the sidebar in ST3, and it does not give that as an option. "Copy File Path" is not there. Any ideas?

Comment: @MattTagg this doesn't work when clicking in the sidebar, you have to click in the body of the file. For working with files in the sidebar, I highly recommend installing the [SideBarEnhancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements) plugin via Package Control.

Comment: @MattDMo ahh got it now. Thanks for the help

Comment: How do you know that `copy_path` is the right command ? How do we know what available ? Is there any docs that I miss ?

Answer (score 1):

For those like me that need a shortcut to copy the **relative path**,

- I installed the [Copy Relative Path package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Copy%20Relative%20Path),
- and added this keybinding:

`{ "keys": ["alt+p"], "command": "copy_relative_path" }`